# google-protobuf - Can't find variable: proto

Tags: javascript, react-native, protocol-buffers, proto

I got an issue using `google-protobuf` (v3.21.0) in `React Native` (v0.65.1) in order to connect device (IoT) via SoftWiFi using `expressif` ([Security1](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/provisioning/provisioning.html#security1-scheme))

After creating succesfully the private and public keys with the curve25519 I need to use protobuf for passing the payload. To do so, I'm following this explanation:
https://medium.com/@singhandresh09/using-protobuf-in-react-native-7cc8286389f5

After have created successfully the js files with the `protoc` compiler I lunch successfully the app.

The error I got refers to the file created by protoc `session_pb.js`:

```
Can't find variable: proto

goog.object.extend(proto, sec0_pb)
```

To replicate it here is what I do.

- First import the js file created.
  `var session_pb = require('../../../proto/session_pb');`

and then used it

```
   const s = new session_pb.S0SessionCmd();
   const r = s.setClientPubKey('123');
```

I've noticed that in the created js files the "proto" is not defined anywhere. Here the file generated:

```
...
// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck

var jspb = require('google-protobuf');
var goog = jspb;
var global = (function() { return this || window || global || self || Function('return this')(); }).call(null);

var sec0_pb = require('./sec0_pb.js');
goog.object.extend(proto, sec0_pb);   <--- here is where the error occurs
var sec1_pb = require('./sec1_pb.js');
goog.object.extend(proto, sec1_pb);
var sec2_pb = require('./sec2_pb.js');
goog.object.extend(proto, sec2_pb);
...
```

[image]

Comment: Coming across this same issue right now, please update with findings!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by disabling the `inlineRequires` in `metro.config.js`.

```js
{
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  }
}
```